# Being fired from previous job wasn't brought up in the interview. Should I be concerned if I have got the job?

Tags: interviewing, job-change

I was recently fired from a part time job. During an interview, I wasn't asked about it at all. I ended up getting the job.

Is there any reason I should be concerned about not bringing it up, or is it their job to ask about being fired in the past?

Answer (score 10):

Don't overthink this.

If "being fired" were an important criterion in making their decision, they would have asked you at some point during the application process. You got the job because they think you are qualified for it. Being fired from a previous job doesn't make you any less qualified for *this* job.

Unless you were fired for doing something bad, like stealing company property or assaulting a coworker, you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

If they did not ask they don't care. Some places might ask and some not. Hiring criteria vary wildly between companies so there is no standard, especially not one that includes asking about a history of being fired.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for you to be concerned as others pointed out but at the same time be prepared with an answer of why you were fired, because this can come up anytime during your employment. (Formally or informally!)
You should have a reasonable explanation of what happened; Honest and humble. Instead of blaming anyone, you can just focus on what you have learnt from that experience to ensure it will not happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has been fired.

Back in the ancient times of the 1980's it was a big deal.  This was back in the day that if someone had two jobs in a lifetime, and one wasn't fast-food or something similar, they were considered job hoppers.

Now, people change jobs frequently, the rise of the "professional manager" has also made people aware of what Dilbert terms the "pointy hair boss".  People can get fired for any reason or no reason at all with part-time jobs being seen as purgatory for the worker, and are not taken seriously with regards to firing.

Nearly everyone who has worked retail, for example, has been fired at least once.

Don't worry about it, just don't make a habit of being fired and you should be fine.